# ntbackup on live system

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2003-r2, ntbackup

I have a few Windows 2003 servers of which I want to take a backup of before installing some anti-virus software. My question is, does ntbackup (the included backup software) operate on a live, running system? Will I run into errors where certain system files are in use?

I've used this to backup unused data, but never on a live system that can't be shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the system state backup will make use of VSS to make copies of files, so you won't run into problems with locked files.